# Can I define setters in python?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I want to create a class in python that has setters for its attributes.

For example suppose we have  a class named `myClass` and it has `x` attribute. I want to create it so that when someone changes x value, only two last digits of x `(x % 100)` are saved.

*using myClass in python shell:*

```
>>> obj = myClass()
>>> obj.x = 352562
>>> obj.x
62
```

Can I define a setter that is called automatically when changing the value of `x`?

Comment: Look into the `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` magic methods

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters/52825556

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use properties decorators

```
@property
def x(self):
    return self._x

@x.setter
def x(self, value):
    self._x = value % 100
```

Also you will have to declare and initialise _x in your **init** method for a safer code

See this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616559/use-cases-for-property-vs-descriptor-vs-getattribute) for more information