# Am I writing a correct decorator?

Tags: python, magic-methods

Recently I was reading something about decorator in *Learning Python*. By following an example of descriptor-as-decorator, I tried to write a different version of it.

```
class tracer3(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        print func # what func should it be: bound, unbound, or function?
        self.calls = 0
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.calls += 1
        print ('call %s to %s' % (self.calls, self.func.__name__))
        return self.func(self.wrapped, *args, **kwargs)

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        self.wrapped = instance
        return self

class Person:
    @tracer3
    def spam(self, say):
        print 'Hello %s' % say

p = Person()
p.spam('world')
```

It yields

> ```
> <function spam at 0x10b0260c8>
> call 1 to spam
> Hello world
> ```

Two questions about it:

1. Is the decorator a correct one? From the result, it seems fine. But I'm just not sure about magic methods I used here.
2. Notice the `print func` in `__init__`. Why `func` here is just a `function` but neither a `bound` nor an `unbound` one? And why `self.func(self.wrapped, *args, **kwargs)` can work by **manually** passing a `self` as first argument? (Is the **method** just a that simple combination of a *function* and a *instance* as 1st argument?)

Comment: First your decorator is applied and then the result of your decorator is bound.

Comment: Just the other day I just wrote up a whole answer explaining about using classes as method decorators: [Callable object decorator applied to method doesn't get self argument on input](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22545339)

Comment: You do **not** want to set `self.wrapped`; that's not thread safe and you can no longer store your bound decorator object and expect it to be still bound to the instance.

Comment: In fact, all your questions are basically answered in that post, so I am voting to close this one as a duplicate.