# Decorator implemented as proxy class cannot decorate class-level method functions....why?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm reading Learning Python by Mark Lutz. I'm currently reviewing chapter 32, Part 1 which discusses Decorators and Metaclasses. Lutz states that the class below cannot be used to decorate class-level method functions. I can see this is true but I'm have some trouble conceptualizing why. As far as I can tell, inside the `__call__` method  self is equal to t, an instance of tracer and args is equal (a,b,c). Shouldn't `self.func(*args)` resolve to 
`tracer.func(t,a,b,c)`? Instead, inside the method I'm calling self becomes equal to 1. why is that?

```
class tracer:
    def __init__(self,f):
        self.counter = 0
        self.func = f
    def __call__(self,*args):
        self.counter += 1
        return self.func(*args)

class Test:
    @tracer
    def spam(self,*args):
        print(a+b+c)

t = Test()
t.spam(1,2,3)
t.spam(1,2,3)
t.spam(1,2,3)
```

Comment: Also see [Callable object decorator applied to method doesn't get self argument on input](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22545339); arguably that is the better dupe target.

Comment: Yes. This is what I'm asking. Thank you!